# What is a 'height field'?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, phase-transition, spin-models

I encountered a few times the expression of ['height fields' in statistical physics](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=%22statistical+physics%22&as_epq=height+field), without ever reading a proper definition. My textbooks don't seem to talk about that, and googling it hasn't been fruitful yet.

Still I know that they are somewhat related to clusters domain (like cluster on spin up or down in the Ising model) for systems with continuous order parameter (such as the $XY$ model). Would you have any bibliographic references to share on this point?

Comment: You flagged the answer by Dave as the one you were looking for, but I'll just briefly mention another, related, usage anyway. If you do a mean field approximation (coarse-graining) of the Ising model, you'll get a continuous order parameter and (the van der Waals) square gradient term (for spatial heterogeneity). If you plot these phase fields (as they are sometimes called), they look like height maps. And indeed the simplest membrane fluctuation theories describing the height of a membrane, like the one due to Helfrich, can be in the Monge parametrization cast into a very similar form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mapping from dimer (and loop) coverings of planar lattices to the configurations of $2-D$ elastic membranes; the "height" is the displacement of the membrane.

I'm aware of the work that Chen Zeng and Jane Kondev did exploring this relationship in the late 1990's, e.g.:
[Chen Zeng et al.  Statistical Topography of Glassy Interfaces Phys. Rev. Lett. Vol. 80, No. 5, 1998](http://home.gwu.edu/~chenz/Publication/Condmat/p109_1.pdf)

A Google search on "height field dimer matching" yielded several relevant documents including

- [Seminar notes by F. Alet](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEkQFjAE&url=http://www.lpt.ups-tlse.fr/IMG/pdf_Dimers-Maths.pdf&ei=enipU9bTMczxoATqsoHQBg&usg=AFQjCNGArFTo2aWto2jph9btNWUnj05rGA&sig2=IMxyl3uzPGSujXGet4sCrg&bvm=bv.69620078,d.cGU), and
- [Lecture notes by R. Kenyon](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http://www.math.brown.edu/~rkenyon/papers/dimerlecturenotes.pdf&ei=3nmpU6-NBZfboASUq4LYBg&usg=AFQjCNHVgyV7lhPiVkdsCMZ1mcJVKHLi2Q&sig2=zILdwGkH1Axv02tYoIiz_g&bvm=bv.69620078,d.cGU&cad=rja)